# Double Partial Derivatives of sum of variances of dependent random variables

Tags: random-variable, derivative

I have the following function 
$$f(α)=Var[αX+(1−α)Y]=Var(αX)+Var[(1−α)Y]+2α(1−α)Cov(X,Y)$$

Partial derivative of this function w.r.t **α** leads us to following result 
$$f′(α)=2αVar(X)−2(1−α)Var(Y)+2Cov(X,Y)(1−2α)=0$$

$$ α=\frac{Var(Y)−Cov(X,Y)} {Var(X)+Var(Y)−2Cov(X,Y} $$

This **α** is the minimum value of the function but in order to prove that it is minimum value, one has to prove that double partial derivative of the function  **f(α)** is greater than **Zero**  i.e.  **f′′(α)** > 0 . 
But upon solving for **f′′(α)** I get

$$f′′(α)=Var(X)+Var(Y)-2Cov(X,Y)$$
$$f′′(α)=Var(X-Y)$$

How can conclude that this **f′′(α)** > 0 . Please help on this.

Comment: What is Var(X-Y)? Expand it out.

Comment: @Glen_b it illustrate that the variance of two number can't be negative hence Var(X-Y) is always positive ? Am i right ?

Comment: 0≤Var(X−Y)=Var(X)+Var(Y)−2Cov(X,Y) Yes i got my answer. Thanks a lot .

Comment: @Glen_b please suggest some source to improve my understanding in this area except wiki.

Comment: Besides reviewing high school algebra, I'd suggest a basic book on calculus (a standard college level first text should do), plus a first book on mathematical statistics -- something along the lines of one of these:
1. Wackerly Mendenhall Scheaffer, *Mathematical Statistics with Applications*,  2. Peter J Smith,  *Into statistics*,  3. Jay L. Devore, *Probability and statistics*, ... , but there are perhaps a dozen others that would be about as good.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38009/discussion-between-user110244-and-glen-b).

Comment: This is an elementary problem in disguise, because (writing $A=\operatorname{Var}(X)$, $C=\operatorname{Var}{Y}$, and $B=\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)$) you have $$f(\alpha) = A\alpha^2 + C(1-\alpha)^2+2B\alpha(1-\alpha)=(A+C-2B)\alpha^2+(2B-2C)\alpha+C$$ which is a quadratic function of $\alpha$. The rest of the analysis follows once you realize $A+C-2B\ge 0$ (and requires no Calculus techniques).

Answer (score 2):

As the [variances is always a non-negative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) and Var(X-Y) is always greater than zero and our equaion leads to the proof that we wanted i.e.
                            $$f''(α)>0$$
So it has been proved that α denotes the minimum value of the function.

A special thanks to @Glen_b who forced me to learn by doing.